# What is embedded SQL?

Tags: sql, delphi

for example, Delphi has components TADOQuery, TADOStoredProcedure, TADOtable.

Do they represent Embedded SQL??

What is the difference between  Embedded SQL and  just using SQL in programming languages??

Comment: Not about programming embedded systems.  Retagged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `TADO*` aren't embedded SQL.

Embedded SQL is a (mostly archaic) technique where you write specially delimited SQL in your code and use a pre-processing application to convert that to direct DB API calls.

You can read about it in [Chapter 14 of the InterBase Embedded SQL guide](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/interbase/IB2009/IB2009_EmbedSQL.pdf) [PDF], if you care to.

Comment: No, `TADO*` don't require a preprocessor. How do they work? It's complicated. At the end of the chain, however, they use the DB's DSQL API.

Answer (score 4):

No those Delphi components are not embedded SQL.  In embedded SQL the SQL statements are intermixed with regular code, the most common form I know of is ESQL/C.  It should be considered deprecated.

The way it works is a preprocessor that translates all the SQL related stuff to the host language, and that pretranslated code is fed through the host language compiler.

A short fragment based on PostgreSQL's ESQL/C implementation:

```
void showesql() {
    EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    int FooBar;
    VARCHAR DooDad;
    EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

    EXEC SQL DECLARE foo_bar CURSOR FOR
        SELECT number, ascii FROM foo
        ORDER BY ascii;
    EXEC SQL OPEN foo_bar;
    EXEC SQL FETCH foo_bar INTO :FooBar, DooDad;
    printf ("number is %d and ascii was %s\n",FooBar, DooDad);
    EXEC SQL CLOSE foo_bar;
    EXEC SQL COMMIT;
}
```

In my experience working in such code is quite hard, and that's why this once pretty common technique has been abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

Embedded SQL is using SQL statements within your program code

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_SQL